# Is [[ ${variable} ]] same as [[ -n ${variable} ]] in bash?

Tags: bash

I read a code which is written by another person in bash.
It includes the following code,

```
[[ ${variable} ]]
```

It seems it works as

```
[[ -n ${variable} ]]
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, without any option inside `[[` (`[[` is a `bash` keyword though), the behavior is exactly same to using the `-n` option i.e. it is checking if the string is non-empty (i.e. length > 0), and gives exit status `0` if the string is not empty as you can imagine.

Comment: thank you for answering. Please let me ask you a little bit more.  When the variable is defined as integer, is there any problem?

Comment: @mora No, like i said it just checks the length, nothing else. Although note that, the integer tests are different and uses `-gt`, -`lt` etc options, `-n` is a pure string test.

Comment: @mora I think is not a keyword, because there is a program called just `[`. Look at `/usr/bin/[`.

Comment: @Peregring-lk There is a shell builtin `[` too (and will get precedence over the external one).